# Parseval's identity, decomposition of inproduct.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Hoi,

if $H$ is a seperable real Hilbertspace and $(e_n)$ orthonormal basis,

then Parseval's identity $$\sum_n\left\langle x,e_n \right\rangle^2 = \left\|x\right\|^2 = \left\langle x,x \right\rangle$$

Is it also true that $$\left\langle x,y\right\rangle = \sum_n \left\langle x,e_n \right\rangle \left\langle y,e_n \right\rangle, $$

holds?

It would clearly be consistent with Parseval, but why is it true if so? I vaguely remember this as a familiar identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\langle x, e_n \rangle = x_n$ since $(e_n)$ forms an orthonormal basis. Similarly $\langle y,e_n \rangle = y_n$ Then what you asked simplifies to

$$ \langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{n} \langle x , e_n \rangle \langle y , e_n \rangle = \sum_{n} x_n y_n, $$

as you are familiar with seeing in the Euclidean case, and have likely seen as the inner product on a Hilbert space before. Just a clarification, this is dependent upon $(e_n)$ being an orthonormal BASIS not just an orthonormal system, similar to Parseval's identity.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\langle x,y\rangle=\sum x_{i}y_{i}$$
very similar to the Euclidean case.

Comment: Sorry, I absolutely don't understand the logical relation between the question and your answer. Maybe more details would make clarify it.

Comment: I suggest you write out $x=\sum x_{i},y=\sum y_{j}$ and do the calculation yourself once.