# Parseval's identity type result for Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Parseval's identity for Hilbert spaces state that if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $(e_i)_{i \in I}$ is its orthonormal basis, then for all $x \in H$ we have
$$
\lVert x \rVert_H^2 = \sum_{i \in I} \left\lvert \langle x, e_i \rangle_H \right\rvert^2.
$$

**Is the following generalization of this result true?**

For all $x,y \in H$ we have
$$
\langle x, y \rangle_H = \sum_{i \in I} \left\lvert \langle x, e_i \rangle_H \langle e_i, y \rangle_H \right\rvert.
$$

It is clearly true for Euclidean spaces, but I am at a loss when it comes to general Hilbert spaces.

[This question's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672596/parsevals-identity-decomposition-of-inproduct) accepted answer seems hand-wavy since I don't see how $\langle x, y \rangle$ equals $\sum_i x_i y_i$.

Edit: Edited the formula to reflect Kavi Rama Murthy's comment.

Comment: What happens if you plug $x=\sum x_ie_i$ and $y=\sum y_je_j$ into $\langle x,y\rangle$?

Comment: The formula you have written is wrong.  It does not hold even in finite dimensions. The correct formula is $
\langle x, y \rangle_H = \sum_{i \in I}  \langle x, e_i \rangle_H \langle  e_i , y\rangle_H $ and this holds in any HS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\ (e_i)_{i\in I}\ $ is an orthonormal basis, then
\begin{align}
x&=\sum_{i\in I}x_ie_i\ \text{, and}\\
y&=\sum_{j\in I}y_je_j\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ x_i=\langle x,e_i\rangle\ $ and $\ y_j=\langle y,e_j\rangle\ $.  Therefore,
\begin{align}
\langle x,y\rangle&=\Big\langle\sum_{i\in I}x_ie_i,\sum_{j\in I}y_je_j\Big\rangle\\
&=\sum_{i\in I}x_i\Big\langle e_i,\sum_{j\in I}y_je_j\Big\rangle\\
&=\sum_{i\in I}x_i\sum_{j\in I}\overline{y}_j\langle e_i,e_j\rangle\\
&=\sum_{i\in I}x_i\overline{y}_i\ ,
\end{align}
by the orthonormality of $\ (e_i)_{i\in I}\ $.  Note that [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672596/parsevals-identity-decomposition-of-inproduct) whose answer you cited was about *real* Hilbert spaces, for which the above identity reduces to
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{i\in I}x_iy_i=\sum_{i\in I}\langle x,e_i\rangle\langle y,e_i\rangle\ .
$$
For a *general* Hilbert space, however, the conjugation must remain in the identity:
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{i\in I}x_i\overline{y}_i=\sum_{i\in I}\langle x,e_i\rangle\overline{\langle y,e_i\rangle}=\sum_{i\in I}\langle x,e_i\rangle\langle e_i,y\rangle\ ,
$$
as given by [Kavi Rama Murthy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy) in his comment.

Comment: How do justify going from $\left\langle \sum_{i \in I} x_i e_i, \sum_{j \in I} y_j e_j \right\rangle$ to $\sum_{i \in I} x_i \left\langle e_i, \sum_{j \in I} y_j e_j \right\rangle$?

Comment: The inner product is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Definition) and continuous (from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) in its first argument.